# How to make text responsive inside a WYSIWYG editor?

Tags: theming

I have some node fields(text areas with WYSIWYG) presented as tabs(using Panels and Panel tabs).
What I want is the text that is inside the WYSIWYG editor to be responsive like the tabs.How can I make this?
thanks
[image: See image attached]

Comment: Is there any online demo? When you offer online demo we can make it responsive by some css code

Comment: Thanks @Drupalist,when I have the online site I will post here.thanks